# An equilateral triangle formed using points of tangency

Tags: geometry, contest-math

P.S:I am looking for a hint and not the whole solution.

BdMO 2012 nationals secondary:

> The vertices of a right triangle $ABC$ inscribed in a circle divide the circumference into three arcs. The 
>   right angle is at $A$, so that the opposite arc BC is a semicircle while arc $AB$ and arc $AC$ are 
>   supplementary. To each of the three arcs, we draw a tangent such that its point of tangency is the 
>   midpoint of that portion of the tangent intercepted by the extended lines $AB$ and $AC$. More precisely, the 
>   point $D$ on arc $BC$ is the midpoint of the segment joining the points $D'$ and $D''$ where the tangent at $D$
>   intersects the extended lines $AB$ and $AC$. Similarly for $E$ on arc $AC$ and $F$ on arc $AB$. Prove that triangle 
>   $DEF$ is equilateral.

[image]

I have tried angle chasing,POP,forming pedal triangles,looking for cyclic quadrilaterals etc..A prod in the correct direction will be appreciated.

NOTE:If possible,please use an elementary approach to the problem.This contest usually emphasizes on Euclidean geometry so there must be a solution using Euclidean geometry.

Answer (score 5):

Per light of @Blue's last comment, here's a (very brief) solution:
[image]
Since $E$ is the midpoint of $E'E''$ and $\angle A=90^\circ$, $\triangle AEE'$ is isosceles at $E$.  It follows that $\angle AEE''=2 \angle EAE'$, equivalently *$E$ trisects the small arc $AC$.*

Similarly, $F$ trisects the small arc $AB$ and $D$ trisects the **large arc** $AC$ (and $AB$).

That would show $\triangle DEF$ is equilateral.

Comment: +1. I was just going to post an identical demonstration (which I'll probably go ahead and do). I hadn't identified $D$ as trisector of the large arcs, though; now it seems obvious. :)

Comment: Looks good to me! I was completely stumped myself.

Comment: Nicest solution.Just a question,how does it follow that E trisects the small arc $AC$ from the angle equalities?I can see that the angles are in the ratio $2:1$. But why must the arcs be in the same ratio?Again,thanks for the solution.

Comment: @rah4927: The "measure" (which is not to say the *length*) of an arc is equal to the measure of the central angle that subtends ("looks at") it; that's definitional. (The *length* of an arc is proportional to its measure, with proportionality factor $r$ ... or $\pi r/180$ if the measure is in degrees.) Since the measure of an inscribed angle is proportional (always with factor $1/2$) to the measure of the central angle that subtends the same arc, we conclude that arcs (in measure or length) are also proportional to these inscribed angle measures.

Answer (score 2):

Coordinatize the triangle on the unit circle via
$$A = (\cos\alpha, \sin\alpha)\qquad B = (-1,0) \qquad C = (1,0)$$ 
Let $T$ be a point of tangency representing generically one of $D$, $E$, $F$.$$T = (\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$$
Define $T_B$ and $T_C$ as points on the tangent line, at distance $t$ from $T$; we can express these as $T \pm t\;T^\perp$, where $T^\perp$ is a unit vector orthogonal to $T$:
$$T_B = T+t\;(\sin\theta,-\cos\theta) \qquad T_C = T-t\;(\sin\theta,-\cos\theta)$$
Forcing $T_B$ to be on line $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$, and $T_C$ to be on line $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$, gives two conditions on the parameter $t$. Eliminating $t$ leaves an equation involving only $\theta$ (and $\alpha$), which has exactly three distinct solutions for $\theta$ equally-spaced about the circle; these are $D$, $E$, $F$.

---

The algebra is much easier if you coordinatize in the complex plane:
$$A = e^{i\alpha}\qquad B = -1 \qquad C = 1$$
Note that, given $T = e^{i\theta}$, we can write $T^\perp$ as $i\;T$, so that
$$T_B =  e^{i\theta} \left( 1 + it \right) \qquad T_C =  e^{i\theta} \left( 1 - it \right)$$ 
As before, imposing collinearity on $A$, $B$, $T_B$, and on $A$, $C$, $T_C$, gives equations in $t$, namely ...

$$\begin{align}
\frac{B - A}{T_B - A} = \frac{\overline{B} - \overline{A}}{\overline{T_B} - \overline{A}} &\quad\to\quad it ( e^{2i\theta} + e^{i\alpha}) = -(e^{i\theta} + 1) (e^{i\theta} - e^{i\alpha}) \\[4pt]
\frac{C - A}{T_C - A} = \frac{\overline{C} - \overline{A}}{\overline{T_C} - \overline{A}} &\quad\to\quad it (e^{2i\theta} - e^{i\alpha}) = \phantom{-}(e^{i\theta}- 1) (e^{i\theta} - e^{i\alpha})
\end{align}$$

Eliminating $t$ here gives an uncomplicated equation 
$$\left(\;e^{i\theta}-e^{i\alpha}\;\right)\left(\;e^{3i\theta}-e^{i\alpha}\;\right)=0$$
with an extraneous root $\theta = \alpha$, and with three symmetrically-arranged solutions $\theta = \frac{1}{3}(\alpha + 2k\pi)$ for $k=0,1,2$, indicating that $D$, $E$, $F$ are vertices of an equilateral triangle.

---

The results of the algebraic approach make the geometry of the situation clear: $E$ and $F$ *trisect* respective arcs $\stackrel{\frown}{AC}$ and $\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$. ($D$'s position is a bit harder to describe.) @QuangHoang posted a demonstration of this fact while I was working on my own; for completeness, here's my analysis:

[image]

Since $\angle PAQ = 90^\circ$, point $A$ lies on the circle about $E$ with diameter $PQ$.
$$\frac{1}{2}\stackrel{\frown}{AE} \;=\; \angle AEP \;=\; 2 \angle EAQ \;=\; \stackrel{\frown}{EC}$$
Thus, $E$ trisects $\stackrel{\frown}{AC}$. Likewise, $F$ trisects $\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$. As @QuangHoang notes, point $D$'s location isn't at all difficult to describe: it simultaneously trisects major arcs $\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$ and $\stackrel{\frown}{AC}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a bit unclear to me. In particular the part “Similarly for $E$ on arc $AC$ and $F$ on arc $AB$” could be interpreted to mean that for $E$ we'd intersect with $BA$ and $BC$ to obtain $E'$ and $E''$, or to intersect again with $AB$ and $AC$. The former was my first interpretation of this question, but in that case the claim is false. The latter is the correct interpretation, since it agrees with your figure and leads to a valid claim.

*Note that there is a simpler approach in the last section of my post, so read that if reading everything is too long for you.*

## Incorrect: intersect with different pairs of edges

For reference I'll leave my original wrong interpretation in place, and build on that later on. I started out with a brutal coordinate-based approach on rational homogeneous coordinates.

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1-a^2\\2a\\1+a^2\end{pmatrix}\qquad
B=\begin{pmatrix}a^2-1\\2a\\1+a^2\end{pmatrix}\qquad
C=\begin{pmatrix}1-a^2\\-2a\\1+a^2\end{pmatrix}\qquad
t\in[0,1]$$

So all four points are on the unit circle, and the legs are aligned to the axes of the coordinate system. $A$ is in the first quadrant. Now do the same for $D,E,F$

$$D=\begin{pmatrix}1-d^2\\2d\\1+d^2\end{pmatrix}\qquad
E=\begin{pmatrix}1-e^2\\2e\\1+e^2\end{pmatrix}\qquad
F=\begin{pmatrix}1-f^2\\2f\\1+f^2\end{pmatrix}$$

You can compute $D', D'', E', E'', F', F''$ from that. Remember that in this approach, I'm obtaining $E'$ and $E''$ by intersecting with $BA$ and $BC$, while I obtain $F'$ and $F''$ by intersecting with $CA$ and $CB$. You can formulate the midpoint condition e.g. in terms of harmonic points, from which you can obtain one relation for each variable $d,e,f$:

\begin{align*}
d^3 + 3ad^2 - 3d - a &= 0 \tag{1} \\
e^3 + (a^3 + 2a)e^2 - (2a^2 + 1)e - a^3 &= 0 \\
(a^2 - 1)f^3 - (3a^3 + 5a)f^2 + (5a^2 + 3)f + (a^3 - a) &= 0
\end{align*}

This allows you to compute each of these variables in terms of $a$. Of the three possible solutions to these cubic equations, each arc between the corners of the triangle will contain exactly one solution for each equation, which means that only one solution will be valid according to your description of the problem. If one turns the parameters (which are in fact the tangens of half the angle) back into normal angles measured in degrees, you can plot the relationship like this:

[image: Plot of angles]

On the horizontal axis you see the angle of $A$, ranging from $0°$ to $90°$. Correspondingly, the middle black line represents $A$, the one above is $B$ and the one below is $C$. Between these are the arcs, color-coded for the point which has to lie in that arc. The solutions for the equation for $d$ are colored blue, and the correct one which defines $D$ is the one on blue background, drawn thicker. Likewise for $E$ and $F$.

I can give an explicit formula for $d$, using the valid solution only. Since this is a solution to a cubic equation, you will need complex numbers along the way even if the final result is real.

$$
d = -\frac{{\left(a^{2} + 1\right)} {\left(i \, \sqrt{3} + 1\right)}}{2 \,
\sqrt[3]{\left(-a^{3} + i \, a^{2} - a + i\right)}} - \frac{1}{2}
\, \sqrt[3]{\left(-a^{3} + i \, a^{2} - a + i\right)} {\left(-i \,
\sqrt{3} + 1\right)} - a
$$

I have similar formulas for $e$ and $f$ as well, but they are more complicated and won't easily fit into the width of this site here. Using these formulas, you can do one example computation, e.g. for $a=\tfrac12$, and in fact see that the thing you want to prove is incorrect in my first interpretation of the statement.

\begin{align*}
a &= 0.5 \\
d &= \left(\frac{2}{25} i + \frac{1}{25}\right) \, \left(\frac{5}{4} i -
\frac{5}{8}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}} {\left(5 i \, \sqrt{3} + 5\right)} -
\frac{1}{2} \, \left(\frac{5}{4} i - \frac{5}{8}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}
{\left(-i \, \sqrt{3} + 1\right)} - \frac{1}{2} \\
d &\approx -2.585514893 \\
e &= -\frac{1}{2} \, {\left(\frac{5}{64} i \, \sqrt{31} -
\frac{139}{512}\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}} {\left(i \, \sqrt{3} + 1\right)} -
\frac{-41 i \, \sqrt{3} + 41}{128 \, {\left(\frac{5}{64} i \, \sqrt{31}
- \frac{139}{512}\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}}} - \frac{3}{8} \\
e &\approx -0.07898307065 \\
f &= {\left(\frac{5}{324} i \, \sqrt{11467} \sqrt{3} -
\frac{34739}{5832}\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}} + \frac{1141}{324 \,
{\left(\frac{5}{324} i \, \sqrt{11467} \sqrt{3} -
\frac{34739}{5832}\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}}} - \frac{23}{18} \\
f &\approx 1.061458191 \\
A &= (+0.6, +0.8) \\
B &= (-0.6, +0.8) \\
C &= (+0.6, -0.8) \\
D   &\approx (-0.739748947, -0.672882973) \\
D'  &\approx (-2.079497895, +0.800000000) \\
D'' &\approx (+0.600000000, -2.145765946) \\
E   &\approx (+0.987600700, -0.156986807) \\
E'  &\approx (+1.139721190, +0.800000000) \\
E'' &\approx (+0.835480210, -1.113973613) \\
F   &\approx (-0.059572990, +0.998223952) \\
F'  &\approx (+0.600000000, +1.037586597) \\
F'' &\approx (-0.719145980, +0.958861307) \\
\alpha   &= 2\arctan(a) \approx +53.13010235° \\
\delta   &= 2\arctan(d) \approx -137.7100341° \\
\epsilon &= 2\arctan(e) \approx -9.032042737° \\
\phi     &= 2\arctan(f) \approx +93.41530306°
\end{align*}

So as you can clearly see, the angles $\delta,\epsilon,\phi$ are *not* $120°$ apart from one another, as they would have to be if they were to form an equilateral triangle. Here is an illustration of the situation computed above:

[image: Counterexample]

## Correct: always intersect with *AB* and *AC*

Seeing the above figure, I noticed that it looks quite different from the illustration in your question. Only then did I notice that you were *always* intersecting with $AB$ and $AC$. Which means you'd not be comparing my $d,e,f$ values, but instead the three possible values of $d$. For these, quick numerical evidence shows that you do indeed get values of $120°$. So now all we have to do is prove that.

Let's revisit equation $(1)$ from above:

$$d^3 + 3ad^2 - 3d - a = 0 \tag{1}$$

I'd like to plug in the $120°$ rotated version of $d$ into that equation. But what is that. This is searching for a $\mathbb{RP}^1$ transformation given three points and their images. A bit of computation will give you

$$r:d\mapsto\frac
{d (\sqrt{3} - 1) - (\sqrt{3} - 3)}
{d (\sqrt{3} - 3) + (\sqrt{3} - 1)}$$

So at that point, all you have to prove is that putting $r(d)$ instead of $d$ itself in equation $(1)$ will give you the same polynomial, up to some common factor in front of the whole left hand side. I have checked that, using sage and algebraic numbers, and it checks out just fine. So whenever $d$ is a solution, the version rotated by $120°$ is a solution as well, which means that the three lines you are asking about will indeed be rotated by $120°$ against one another.

## Simpler approach

The graphs up there look a lot as if the blue lines were straight. Numerical evidence supports that assumption as well. So here would be a different approach for a proof, avoiding projective geometry and all that. The idea is that while $A$ rotates at a given speed, starting at $0°$, $D$ will rotate at one third of that speed, starting at $-120°$. Since dividing an angle into three equal parts is much harder than tripling an angle, we'll parametrize by the angle of the slower movement of points $D,E,F$. So we define $s:=\sin(\theta)$ and $c:=\cos(\theta)$ for $\theta\in[0°,30°]$. Then for the faster points $A,B,C$ you have

\begin{align*}
\sin(3\theta) &= 3c^2s - s^3 \\
\cos(3\theta) &= c^3 - 3s^2c
\end{align*}

Based on these you can choose coordinates as follows:

\begin{align*}
A &= \begin{pmatrix}c^3 - 3s^2c\\3c^2s - s^3\end{pmatrix} &
B &= \begin{pmatrix}3s^2c - c^3\\3c^2s - s^3\end{pmatrix} &
C &= \begin{pmatrix}c^3 - 3s^2c\\s^3 - 3c^2s\end{pmatrix} \\
D &= \frac12\begin{pmatrix}-c-\sqrt3s\\-\sqrt3c+s\end{pmatrix} &
E &= \begin{pmatrix}c\\-s\end{pmatrix} &
F &= \frac12\begin{pmatrix}-c+\sqrt3s\\\sqrt3c+s\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
D' &= \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{- s^4 + \sqrt3 s^3 c + 3 s^2 c^2 - 3 \sqrt3 s c^3 - 2}{\sqrt3 s + c} \\[1ex]
- s^3 + 3 s c^2
\end{pmatrix} &
D'' &= \begin{pmatrix}
-3 s^2 c + c^3 \\[1ex]
\frac{-3 \sqrt3 s^3 c - 3 s^2 c^2 + \sqrt3 s c^3 + c^4 + 2}{s - \sqrt3 c}
\end{pmatrix} \\
E' &= \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{-2 s^4 + 6 s^2 c^2 + 2}{2 c} \\[1ex]
- s^3 + 3 s c^2
\end{pmatrix} &
E'' &= \begin{pmatrix}
-3 s^2 c + c^3 \\[1ex]
\frac{6 s^2 c^2 - 2 c^4 + 2}{-2 s}
\end{pmatrix} \\
F' &= \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{- s^4 - \sqrt3 s^3 c + 3 s^2 c^2 + 3 \sqrt3 s c^3 - 2}{-\sqrt3 s + c} \\[1ex]
- s^3 + 3 s c^2
\end{pmatrix} &
F'' &= \begin{pmatrix}
-3 s^2 c + c^3 \\[1ex]
\frac{3 \sqrt3 s^3 c - 3 s^2 c^2 - \sqrt3 s c^3 + c^4 + 2}{s + \sqrt3 c}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Now you can verify the three midpoint conditions to see that this is indeed a solution. Keep in mind that $s^2+c^2=1$ since you'll need that to verify that claim. The way $D,E,F$ were constructed they are already $120°$ rotated against one another, so they form an equilateral triangle. Now all you need is a good argument as to why this equilateral triangle is the only valid solution. In my previous approach this could be easily deduced from the degree of the polynomial, but here you'll probably be better of with some kind of monotonicity argument to show that $D,E,F$ are uniquely defined by $A,B,C$.

[image: Animation]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.Unfortunately,I haven't learned projective geometry yet.

Comment: @rah4927: I've updated my question and now have a section which avoids relying on projective geometry.

Comment: The key geometric notion seems to be that $E$ and $F$ *trisect* respective arcs $\stackrel{\frown}{AC}$ and $\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$. ($D$'s position is harder to describe.) This is readily shown with the complex coordinatization I describe in my answer. (I didn't mention the trisections explicitly because OP wanted a *hint*, but perhaps I should go ahead and provide a complete solution.) There's likely a clever geometric argument for these trisections, but I haven't found it yet. :/

Comment: I can see how you would be reluctant to throw away all that hard work! But really most of this is redundant, and distracts from the real answer. Perhaps you could prune it down?